# Limiting user profile size with VBScript on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, cmd, vbscript, windows-10, quota

I need to set a size limit on user profiles and then delete them once they exceed the limit. The most success I've had is with this script

```vb
Set colDiskQuotas = CreateObject("Microsoft.DiskQuota.1")
colDiskQuotas.Initialize "C:\", True

Set objUser = colDiskQuotas.AddUser("aaa") 
Set objUser = colDiskQuotas.FindUser("aaa")
objUser.QuotaLimit = 200000000 '200mb quota 

objUser.QuotaState = 2

If objUser.QuotaState = 2 Then 
    WScript.Echo "Quota state: Enabled and enforced" 
ElseIf objUser.QuotaState = 1 Then 
    WScript.Echo "Quota state: Enabled but not enforced" 
Else 
    WScript.Echo "Quota state: Disabled" 
End If 

'Sets C:\ limit to 200mb
colDiskQuotas.DefaultQuotaLimit = 200000000
colDiskQuotas.DefaultQuotaThreshold = 190000000
WScript.Echo "Default quota limit: " & (colDiskQuotas.DefaultQuotaLimit / 1000000) 'displays quota in megabytes
WScript.Echo "Default warning limit: " & _ 
    (colDiskQuotas.DefaultQuotaThreshold / 1000000) 'displays quota threshold in megabytes
```

The bottom portion of the script successfully sets the disk quota to 200 MB, but that's unfortunately not what I need to do and was only a test. The portion dealing with user 'aaa' is the important part but throws me an error saying the account does not exist. I got this code online and it's my first exposure to VBScript, just as a side-note.

I've also tried the `fsutil` CLI command and I've tinkered with the WMI class `DiskQuota` in Powershell but have not had any luck with either of them.